# Hiding exec output in a SQL Server 2008 stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, exec, output

We have clients running SQL Server 2008 RC up to SQL Server 2014 and the application is so far version agnostic.

I am having some issues with returning a response from a stored procedure which in turn runs SSIS packages through.

SQL Server 2012+

```
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] 
     @package_name = N'packagename.dtsx', 
     @execution_id = @execution_id OUTPUT, 
     @folder_name = N'folder', 
     @project_name = N'myProject', 
     @use32bitruntime = False, 
     @reference_id = Null

EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id
```

This is silent and returns no output so only our `SELECT` is returned.

YET

In older versions SSISDB hadn't been written and you have to run a old fashioned Exec.

```
declare @cmd varchar(5000)
set @cmd = 'DTEXEC /DTS "\MSDB\Import\PackageName" '
EXEC @status = xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

And this is very verbose by spitting out all of the SSIS package info.

> Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
>   Version 10.50.4000.0 for 64-bit
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.
>
> Started:  15:03:50
>   Progress: 2014-09-30 15:03:50.36
>   Source: Import File to Staging Table
>   Validating: 0% complete
>   End Progress
>   Progress: 2014-09-30 15:03:50.36
>   Source: Import File to Staging Table
>   Validating: 25% complete
>   End Progress
>   Progress: 2014-09-30 15:03:50.39

There for I can't map a single Entity Framework stored procedure to both as the responses differ.

How can I make Exec silent?

I've tried `SET NOCOUNT ON` but it is not the issue it is the actually "output" from the Exec (SSIS).

I might be able to put the running of the procedure in a separate procedure when running on a version lower than 2012 but this seems a little overkill just to make a exec non verbose.

Comment: The other thing to be aware of is that people can still use the Package deployment model with 2012/2014 so you might not be able to draw a clean line between versions and their execution models. Unless you're controlling the delivery of these packages and then I'll go bury my head in the sand

Comment: @billinkc We have a deployments team, everything is managed. Sadly we can't control our clients software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was only 2 fields I needed to return so I resorted to adding them as output paramaters. This will be annoying for procs with more output or collections in the future; though for now it is fine.

Stored proc params

```
(
    @schemaId int,
    @companyCode char(2),
    @companyName nvarchar(100),
    @transactionId nvarchar(15) OUTPUT,
    @RtnStatus int OUTPUT
```

)

Entity Query

```
ObjectParameter rtnStatus = new ObjectParameter("RtnStatus", typeof(int?));
ObjectParameter transactionId = new ObjectParameter("TransactionId", typeof(string));
_dataContext.spFixedWidthDataImportSSIS(schemaId, companyCode, companyName, rtnStatus, transactionId).FirstOrDefault();
DataToolsTransactionDto dto = new DataToolsTransactionDto((int?)rtnStatus.Value, transactionId.Value.ToString());
```

This did seem an abstract approach just to hide some output data from a DTEXEC though.

Answer (score 0):

Tell [dtexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810(v=sql.105).aspx) to be quiet then ;)

```
DTEXEC /DTS "\MSDB\Import\PackageName" /REP N
```

That `/REP N` indicates that you want No reporting to occur.

That's still going to generate a minimum amount of text though

```
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 10.50.4319.0 for 32-bit
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.

Started:  9:53:28 AM
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_SUCCESS (0).
Started:  9:53:28 AM
Finished: 9:53:29 AM
Elapsed:  1.045 seconds
```

You could try redirecting output to a file with the `>` but I seem to recall there being some wonkiness with that approach when run through xp_cmdshell.

```
DTEXEC /DTS "\MSDB\Import\PackageName" /REP N  > foo.txt
```

Comment: So close yet so far. Knowing about /REP N is great but as long as it is exists the mapping will fail. I'll look into output to file though thanks.